# Trying to show a probability equation by induction

Tags: probability, induction

Suppose $A_1,...,A_n$ are events, then

$$ P( \bigcup A_i ) = \sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i) - \sum_{i <j}P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{i < j < k}P(A_i\cap A_j \cap A_k) - ... + (-1)^{n+1} P( \bigcap_i A_i) $$

I have shown that this works for the case $n=2$, but I am having difficulty to show that general case. Can we show this by induction? or there is a better way to solve it? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write the result more concisely as $$P\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\sum_{\underset{|S| = i}{S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, n\}}} P(A_S),$$

where $P(A_S) := P(A_{j_1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{j_k})$ if $S = \{j_1,\ldots, j_k\}$. For the inductive step, assume $n > 1$ and the result is true for $n$. Let $A_1,\ldots, A_{n+1}$ be a sequence of $n+1$ events. Let $B_n := A_1 \cup \cdots A_n$. Then

\begin{align}
&P\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n+1} A_n\right)\\
&= P(B_n \cup A_{n+1})\\
&= P(B_n) + P(A_{n+1}) - P(B_n\cap A_{n+1})\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\sum_{\underset{|S| = i}{S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, n\}}} P(A_S) + P(A_{n+1}) - P\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n (A_i \cap A_{n+1}) \right) & (*)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\sum_{\underset{|S| = i}{S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, n\}}} P(A_S) + P(A_{n+1}) - \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{i-1} \sum_{\underset{|S| = i}{S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, n\}}} P(A_S \cap A_{n+1}) & (**)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^{i-1} \sum_{\underset{|S| = i,\, n+1\notin S}{S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}}} P(A_S) + P(A_{n+1}) + \sum_{i = 2}^{n+1} (-1)^{i-1} \sum_{\underset{|S| = i,\, n+1\in S}{S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, n+1\}}} P(A_S)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} (-1)^{i-1} \sum_{\underset{|S| = i}{S\subseteq \{1,2,\ldots, n+1\}}} P(A_S),
\end{align}

as desired. (Note: The induction hypothesis was used in (*) and (**).)

Comment: Why is your first equation right? How the probablity of the union can be written in such way?

Comment: Sure. Notice that the right hand side of your equation has terms of the form $$(-1)^{\ell - 1} \sum_{1 \le i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_\ell \le n} P(A_{i_1} \cdots A_{i_\ell})$$ where $1 \le \ell \le n$. The indexing sets of these sums correspond to subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ of cardinality $\ell$ for $1 \le \ell \le n$.

Comment: I think you got a typo in the fifth equality( Shouldnt it be $i_{n+1} \notin S $ ?). How does equality fourth imply equality fifth?

Comment: There's no typo there, it's supposed to be $n+1\notin S$.

Comment: but you have defined $S = \{ j_1,...,j_k \} $. Im very confused

Comment: The sums you're referring to are extended over all subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ of a given cardinality $i$, and these subsets correspond to the subsets $S$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, n+1\}$ of a given cardinality $i$ where $n + 1\notin S$.

Comment: @ILoveMath explain where you're confused so I can help you.

Comment: I am confused how you get from equality $4$ to equality $5$. Can you explain a bit more why this is the case? thanks

Comment: Ok. See the first sum in equality $5$. Break it up as $P(A_1) + \cdots + P(A_n) + \text{other}$. Now see the last sum. Break that up as $\text{other} + (-1)^nP(A_1)\cdots P(A_n)$. If you regroup the terms, equality $5$ has $$P(A_1) + \cdots + P(A_{n+1}) + \text{other} + (-1)^nP(A_1)\cdots P(A_{n+1}).$$ The first piece, $P(A_1) + \cdots + P(A_n)$ contributes as the $i = 1$ summand in equality $6$. The last piece, $(-1)^nP(A_1)\cdots P(A_{n+1})$ contributes as the $i = n+1$ summand in equality $6$. Can you figure what the "other" piece is?

Comment: It's $$\sum_{i = 2}^n (-1)^{i-1}\left(\sum_{S,\, |S| = i,\, n+1\notin S} P(A_S) + \sum_{S,\, |S| = i,\, n+1\in S} P(A_S)\right),$$ which simplifies to $$\sum_{i = 2}^n (-1)^{i-1}\sum_{S,\, |S| = i} P(A_S),$$ as a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots, n+1\}$ either contains $n+1$ or it doesn't.